# Анимация маленьких блоков

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, анимация

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеется вот такой вот блок, задача состоит в том чтобы бирюзовые блоки перемещались на пустое место(пустое голубое пространство). 
Посоветуйте пожалуйста какой-нибудь плагин или же можете подкинуть идейку.

Comment: Я не вижу серых блоков

Comment: Прошу прощения , бирюзовые блоки

Comment: Каким образом они должны перемещаться ?

Comment: асинхронно, по пустому голубому пространству, каждый квадрат по отдельности имеет свою траекторию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поделим наше поле на квадраты и представим все это дело в виде матрицы (двумерного массива). 0 и 1 обозначают свободен или занят квадрат соответственно. По циклу проходим по массиву квадратов - содержит положение квадрата в матрице. Квадрат может двигаться в 4 направлениях. Генерируем рандомное число от 1 до 4. Запускаем js скрипт анимации квадрата (можно использовать jq animate и динамически менять свойства left и top), в матрице освобождаем занятую ранее клетку и занимаем новую. Картинка оживает.

Comment: Благодарю, буду пробовать

Comment: Хватит одной матрицы и не забудьте проверку на выход  из размеров матрицы. А так же, думаю понятно, что нужна проверка, занята ли та клетка, куда хочет двигаться квадрат, если занята, то запускаем родном заново с уменьшенным на 1 диапозоном и так до победного.